# HDD smart "read error rate"; is my drive dying?

Tags: hard-drive

I am just wondering if my newly bought drive is about to die (it's less than 1/2 year old).

I just got Scrutiny working on my server machine (linux) which basically is a HDD monitoring tool. I see one of my drives (the newest one, only 114 days old) as `failed` with red text, indicating that something is wrong with the drive. I have tried to run smartmontools on the drive and it says `"PASSED"`. I have taken the drive out and tested it with CrystalDiskInfo too, to be sure, and it also said `"Good"` but with the same error rate and same values as Scrutiny gave me. Should I be worried? Should I contact the place I bought the drive from and get a replacement? Or is this value non-crucial? Is there something else I could check to be sure if the drive is already failing or if it's okay?

Here's an screenshot of the details:
[image]

EDIT:
Short test:

```
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      2731         -
```

EDIT 2: `smartctl -a /dev/sdg`
https://pastebin.com/hxgi0pzt

EDIT 3: HEX48 format of the read error rate: `0x00000af2e996`

EDIT 4: Solved! Thanks to everyone in the comments. Conclusion; drive is NOT dying. Thank god. Calculating the HEX48 value of the read-error-rate gets me to 0 errors in 183,691,670 operations (using this tool https://yksi.ml).

Comment: run `# smartctl -l selftest /dev/sdg` and show the output; as a text, can be in (edited) question.

Comment: Read Error Rate is definitely a metric that reflects the health of the disk (many others are not really), so yes, be concerned. I'd get a backup of it asap, and if you can't get a clean backup, try imaging it with ddrescue.

Comment: `man smartctl` is your friend. Start with `smartctl -t short <device>` and you'll see what's going to come out. Later maybe `long` but first start simple with `short`.

ED: then try `long` (this one is long and takes time)

Comment: @FrankThomas Already contacted the place where I bought it, and the drive works for now. I would need them to send a replacement drive though, as I don't have 16TB of extra space just laying around atm. :laughing: I'll backup what I can for now after the long test is done running tomorrow evening.

Comment: @tansy Will post another edit tomorrow for the long test. Thanks.

Comment: whenever I get a new high capacity disk, I always spend like 3 days getting it going. I do a full format (usually NTFS) and then a thorough-mode chkdsk scan to find and reallocate any bad blocks, and then check the SMART stats, and perhaps perform an extended SMART test. if no sectors were reallocated, pending, or uncorrectable, etc and the raw read and raw write error rates are very low, then I keep it and format it btrfs for my NAS. otherwise it goes right back.

Comment: A long selftest is not top priority. Show us the complete data running smartctl -a /dev/sdg >mylog.txt Show the complete log file please.

Comment: Added a pastebin for `smartctl -a /dev/sdg`

Comment: From screenshot it appears like Seagate HDD. Please also see this answer before concluding. https://superuser.com/questions/1377466/hdd-smart-interpretation-possible-impending-drive-failure/1377501#1377501

Comment: Correct. It's a seagate drive. I got the hex48 format of the read error. Editing post.

Comment: @patkim You can post as answer and I'll check it as solved as that helped out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The drive in question is a Seagate Drive and Seagate measures Read Error Rate and Seek Error Rate differently.

The first 4 nibbles of 48 bit represent the actual error count and last 8 represent the number of seeks. The Read Error Rate is then calculated using a formula and it may be very well below 100 or the initial value which is generally high at 100.

So unlike other parameters, for Seagate Drives it's normal that after a few operations the Read Error Rate and Seek Error Rate fall below 100. What matters is the actual Error Count which is in the first 4 nibbles of 48 bit SMART value.

This question is almost similar to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1377466/hdd-smart-interpretation-possible-impending-drive-failure/) question on SU and has already been answered there.  Hence this post only summarizes things. Please see the other Q&A for further tech details.

Additionally as reported by OP, this calculator  https://yksi.ml/ helps to separate these two values for Seagate Drives.